# Behaviour of RTF in browsers

Tags: browser, rtf

I am receiving text from a backend and displaying it on my web page. The text could be in one of three formats: plain text, HTML, and RTF. I am sure the first two will render without any problems, or loss of formatting.

Will RTF be interpreted and rendered properly by web browsers?

Answer (score 1):

No, RTF will not render at all.

Comment: Hi Albert , Thanks for your reply.Howcome yahoo, gmail,hotmail supports emails in rtf formate ? If I have to do similar kind of thing then what I have to do  ? I would be really thankful if you can give me some pointers.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The actual browser itself will not render the RTF directly because a browser renders html.

However, the browser will receive the RTF sent from the server and will launch whatever default RTF editor is in place on the end users system.  By default on windows, this is typically wordPad.

However if an end user has Microsoft Word in place or another RTF editor this could be the editor that gets launched. The end user will then be able to read the RTF in this editor.

On my system pushing RTF to a client will launch Word and give me the option to either Open or Save the RTF file immediately.

I hope this helps out.